# Need a SQL query statement for this case

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the structure of the table

```
mysql> select * from p1;
+----------+-------+-----------+
| username | token | last_used |
+----------+-------+-----------+
| a        | aacs  |         5 |
| d        | dddd  |         3 |
| a        | aaaaa |         3 |
+----------+-------+-----------+
```

How can I delete the record who has the minimum last_used value from the set queried by username?
In this case ,the given username parameter is 'a',then I shold delete the record **'a','aaaaa',3** because 3 is smaller than 5(the username of last_used(5) is 'a',too).

My answer is

```
delete from persistent_logins 
where last_used=(select * 
                 from (select MIN(last_used) 
                       from persistent_logins where username=?)as t
                 ) 
  and username=?
```

but it's useful,I need a statement like `delete .... from..where username=?`
**It is important that only one parameter is allowed.But my answer has two parameter.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with `DELETE`.  The rows will be deleted in that order with `LIMIT` controlling how many are deleted.

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the rows are deleted in the order that is specified. The LIMIT clause places a limit on the number of rows that can be deleted.

<sub>(From: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)</sub>

Try something like this:

```
DELETE FROM p1
WHERE username = ?
ORDER BY last_used ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I was going to create a `row_id`, but looks like this should work. But looks a little scary the first time I saw it.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta be careful with `DELETE`.  When I was writing the answer, I was a little scared that I had typed the query wrong.  I suggest creating a *test* database to run this on first to double-check.  Also, you can do `SELECT * FROM p1 WHERE username = ? ORDER BY last_used ASC LIMIT 1` to see what rows would be deleted.  You can also run the `DELETE` inside a transaction (I think) and double-check (using `SELECT`) that everything is ok before committing.

Comment: Thank you for your patience answer, I also thought of the answer . Thank you